# How to use Boolean operators in an If statement in Python

Tags: python

I just read a [tutorial](https://realpython.com/python-and-operator/) on Boolean operators in Python, but I can't get my head around how I can use an `if`  statement together with `and`.

For example, this doesn't seem to work well:

```python
# variable1 = 'lorem'
variable2 = 'ipsum'

if 'variable1' and 'variable2' in locals():
    print('Both exist')
else:
    print('Only variable:', variable1, 'exist')
```

It gives me `Both exist` when in fact only one variable exist.

So instead of a boolean approach, I tried using multiple `if` loops like this:

```python
# variable1 = 'lorem'
variable2 = 'ipsum'

if 'variable1' in locals():
    if 'variable2' in locals():
        print('Both exist')
else:
    print('Only variable:', variable1, 'exist')
```

But this raises an `NameError: name 'variable1' is not defined. Did you mean: 'variable2'?`.

To be clear, my question is **not** how to check if a variable exists. My question is how to check if two variables exist with Boolean operators.

*I am fully aware that I have commented out variable1. That is the whole point*.

Edit: Since this question got duped as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18676823/checking-if-two-variables-are-in-the-same-list) one, I must state that this is not about finding variables in a list. Therefore it is not the same question.

Comment: This is a mixture of "variable variables" and "check multiple values in list"

Comment: It's not really "variable variables". The name of the variable doesn't change. The existence of the variable does. Also, I don't see where the list comes in here.

Comment: The [variable variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables) refers to creating some variables, but not others: The names should be keys to a `dict`. The [list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18676823/checking-if-two-variables-are-in-the-same-list) is where you are checking the two names in `locals()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if 'variable1' and 'variable2' in locals():
```

can be correctly expressed as

```
if ('variable1' in locals()) and ('variable2' in locals()):
```

As for your `NameError`: you are executing the `print` after determining that `'variable1'` is *not* in `locals()` (in Python, indentation matters), so this is the behavior you should expect.